# How to map ggplot histogram x-axis intervals to fixed colour palette?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to stratify my ggplot2 histogram into fixed intervals and colour them based on a *specific* colour palette: `'x<4':black; '4<x<6':blue; '6<x<8':yellow`; and so on...

I tried 2 ways, both of which didn't work.

Referring to my code below, alternative 1 fails when `NoOfElement` falls to a small figure, say, 500, and there is no element in the first interval `'x<4'`. ggplot2 then assigns 'black' to whichever is the first interval (this would be `'4<x<6'` when size=500). But this is not what I want (see picture).

[image]

In Alternative 2, I created another variable in my data frame and assigned the colours for each element. I did this based on a modification of the solution given in: [Set specific fill colors in ggplot2 by sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910218/set-specific-fill-colors-in-ggplot2-by-sign). Unfortunately, the resulting histogram has colours randomly assigned by ggplot2.

I'm quite stuck and would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)

NoOfElement <- 5000; MyBreaks <- c(-Inf, seq(4, 16, by=2), Inf)
MyColours <- c("black", "blue", "yellow", "green", "gray", "brown", "purple", "red")

set.seed(2)
c <- data.frame(a=rnorm(NoOfElement, 10, 2), b=rep(NA, NoOfElement))
c$b <- cut(c$a, MyBreaks)

try <- 1  # Allows toggling of alternatives below
if (try==1)
{
  p <- ggplot( c, aes(x=c$a, fill=c$b) ) + geom_histogram( binwidth=0.2 ) + 
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = levels(c$b), values = MyColours, 
                      name = "X Intervals") + 
    scale_x_continuous( limits=c(2, 20))
}else
{
  c$BarCol <- factor(c$b, levels = levels(c$b), labels = MyColours)

  p <- ggplot( c, aes(x=c$a, fill=c$b) ) + geom_histogram( binwidth=0.2 ) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c$BarCol, name = "X Intervals") + 
    scale_x_continuous( limits=c(2, 20))
}
plot (p)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `drop` argument in `scale_` family for empty levels:

```
NoOfElement <- 500; MyBreaks <- c(-Inf, seq(4, 16, by=2), Inf) 
MyColours <- c("black", "blue", "yellow", "green", "gray", "brown", "purple", "red")

set.seed(2) 
c <- data.frame(a=rnorm(NoOfElement, 10, 2), b=rep(NA, NoOfElement)) 
c$b <- cut(c$a, MyBreaks)

p <- ggplot( c, aes(x=c$a, fill=c$b) ) + geom_histogram( binwidth=0.2 ) + 
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = levels(c$b), values = MyColours, 
                      name = "X Intervals", drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818835/geom-boxplot-from-ggplot2-forcing-an-empty-level-to-appear).

Comment: this perfectly answers my question. Thanks so much for your quick response!