# How to format the x-axis of the hard coded plotting function of SPEI package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis, axis-labels

I am using the SPEI package along with its sample monthly data of 32 years. I want to modify the x-axis labels to reflect the years not the numbers. However, the hard coded plotting function won't allow me to do this. I tired to extract the `SPEI$fitted` data and tried to replicate the same plot with ggplot but did not succeeded. Here is the sample code

```
install.packages("SPEI")
library(SPEI)
data("wichita")
wichita$PET=hargreaves(Tmin=wichita$TMIN, Tmax = wichita$TMAX, lat = 37.64)
wichita$BAL=wichita$PRCP - wichita$PET
SPEI_12=spei(wichita[,"BAL"],12)
plot.spei(SPEI_12, main = 12-Month SPEI)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I want to produce a graph like attached.[image]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135962/how-to-fill-geom-polygon-with-different-colors-above-and-below-y-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did not quite understand the `plot.spei` function, so I used `ggplot2`.

Basically I built a data frame with ts of the fitted values and created a color/fill [condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12910865/9699371) for positive (`pos`) or negative (`neg`) values.

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)
DF <- zoo::fortify.zoo(SPEI_12$fitted)
DF <- DF %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Index) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Period = zoo::as.yearmon(paste(wichita$YEAR, wichita$MONTH), "%Y %m")) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(sign = ifelse(ET0_har >= 0, "pos", "neg"))

ggplot2::ggplot(DF) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Period, y = ET0_har, col = sign, fill = sign),
            show.legend = F, stat = "identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("pos" = "darkblue", "neg" = "red")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("pos"  = "darkblue", "neg" = "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3, 3), 
                     breaks = -3:3) +
  ylab("SPEI") + ggtitle("12-Month SPEI") +
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

---

**Edit**: An additional idea.

```
DF2 <- DF %>% 
  tidyr::spread(sign, ET0_har) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

ggplot2::ggplot(DF2) + 
  geom_area(aes(x = Period, y = pos), fill = "blue", col = "black") +
  geom_area(aes(x = Period, y = neg), fill = "red",  col = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3, 3), 
                     breaks = -3:3) +
  ylab("SPEI") + ggtitle("12-Month SPEI") +
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @bbiasi, this will do. Yeah, the `plot.spei` function is hard coded that does not offer the flexibility of desired changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(ts(spei(object, freq = 12, start = c(year, 1)),scale =3))
```

Try this