# Standardized Precipitation index using SPEI

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to develop Standardized Precipitation Index(SPI) using Wichita data provided in R for which I am using "SPEI" package. I can generate SPI figure, however, the quality is not good for publication. I found a very similar question asked here:
[How to format the x-axis of the hard coded plotting function of SPEI package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960836/how-to-format-the-x-axis-of-the-hard-coded-plotting-function-of-spei-package-in/57714577#57714577).

When I tried the code provided in the above link, I could generate good quality figure for SPEI but not for SPI. I had problem in the following line:
`dplyr::mutate(sign = ifelse(ET0_har >= 0, "pos", "neg"))` of the code. My specific question is what should I use instead of "ET0_har" in order to generate SPI in the above line?

I would appreciate your input to generate SPI figure like provided in the above link. Here is my codes:

```
install.packages("SPEI")
library(SPEI)
data("wichita")
SPI1<-spi(wichita$PRCP,scale = 1, distribution = 'Gamma')
plot(SPI1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to:

```
dplyr::mutate(sign = ifelse(`Series 1` >= 0, "pos", "neg"))
```

then it works.