# Displaying SPEI with ggplot: geom_area ends/starts at different positions when sign changes

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-area

Here's some data

```
structure(list(Period = structure(c(2017.83333333333, 2017.91666666667, 
2018, 2018.08333333333, 2018.16666666667, 2018.25, 2018.33333333333, 
2018.41666666667, 2018.5, 2018.58333333333, 2018.66666666667, 
2018.75, 2018.83333333333, 2018.91666666667, 2019, 2019.08333333333, 
2019.16666666667, 2019.25, 2019.33333333333, 2019.41666666667, 
2019.5), class = "yearmon"), neg = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
-0.782066446199374, -1.33087717414387, -1.55401649141939, -1.9056578851487, 
-2.19869230289699, -1.99579537718088, -2.03857957860623, -2.14184701726747, 
-2.27461866979037, -2.39022691659445, -2.3732334198156, -1.83686080707261, 
-1.86553025598681), pos = c(0.550567625206492, 0.699954781241267, 
0.775518140437689, 0.647367030217637, 0.84562688020279, 0.923814518387379, 
0.686796306801202, 0.131849327496122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 960:980, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot the SPEI values with ggplot as I learned it here: 
[How to format the x-axis of the hard coded plotting function of SPEI package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960836/how-to-format-the-x-axis-of-the-hard-coded-plotting-function-of-spei-package-in)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test) + 
  geom_area(aes(x = Period, y = pos), fill = "blue", col = "black") +
  geom_area(aes(x = Period, y = neg), fill = "red",  col = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2.25, 2.25), 
                     breaks = -2:2) +
  ylab("SPEI") + xlab("") +
  theme_bw()
```

The result looks like this: [image: SPEI]

As you can see, when the sign changes from positive to negative, geom_area doesn't end/start at the same position. Anyone any idea how to fix this? I thought about using `Date` instead of `yearmon`, but got stuck with the same problem.

Comment: This might be due to your `Period` as it is not in proper year-month format. Is this a monthly data?

Comment: It is, and the format is ```yearmon``` from ```zoo```

Comment: @BappaDas I don't think it's that easy, ```as.Date``` doesn't do the trick: ```as.Date(format(Period, "%Y-%m-01"))``` produces the same plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gates and posts problem: Each geom_area at the inflection is starting and ending on a post, hence the overlap. They should be starting in the middle of the gate between the posts.

This solution may be a bit heavy handed but I think it should apply where there are multiple changes from positive to negative and vice versa.

```r
  library(ggplot2)
  library(tidyr)
  library(tibble)
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  library(imputeTS)
```

Determine when the data changes from positive to negative or vice versa

```
  inflections <- 
    test %>% 
    mutate(inflect = case_when(lag(neg) == 0 & pos == 0 ~ TRUE,
                                  lag(pos) == 0 & neg == 0 ~ TRUE,
                                  TRUE ~ FALSE),
           rowid = row_number() - 0.5) %>%
    filter(inflect) %>% 
    select(-inflect) %>% 
    mutate(Period = NA_Date_,
           pos = 0, 
           neg = 0)
```

Insert a new row to mark the inflection point to allow inclusion of an intermediary time where both `pos` and `neg` can be zero.

```
test1 <- 
  test %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  bind_rows(inflections) %>% 
  arrange(rowid)
```

Impute a time when the data changes from `pos` to `neg` with a function from `imputeTS`.

```
test1$Period <- na_interpolation(as.ts(test1$Period))
```

plot

```
    ggplot(test1) + 
      geom_area(aes(x = Period, y = pos), fill = "blue", col = "black") +
      geom_area(aes(x = Period, y = neg), fill = "red",  col = "black") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2.25, 2.25), 
                         breaks = -2:2) +
      ylab("SPEI") + xlab("") +
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

````r
data

```
 test <-   structure(list(Period = structure(c(2017.83333333333, 2017.91666666667, 
    2018, 2018.08333333333, 2018.16666666667, 2018.25, 2018.33333333333, 
    2018.41666666667, 2018.5, 2018.58333333333, 2018.66666666667, 
    2018.75, 2018.83333333333, 2018.91666666667, 2019, 2019.08333333333, 
    2019.16666666667, 2019.25, 2019.33333333333, 2019.41666666667, 
    2019.5), class = "yearmon"), neg = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    -0.782066446199374, -1.33087717414387, -1.55401649141939, -1.9056578851487, 
    -2.19869230289699, -1.99579537718088, -2.03857957860623, -2.14184701726747, 
    -2.27461866979037, -2.39022691659445, -2.3732334198156, -1.83686080707261, 
    -1.86553025598681), pos = c(0.550567625206492, 0.699954781241267, 
    0.775518140437689, 0.647367030217637, 0.84562688020279, 0.923814518387379, 
    0.686796306801202, 0.131849327496122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 960:980, class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
````