# How to make SPI plots using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

This is my first question on this platform, though I have thoroughly used it to solve many problems in R programming.

(1) I am stuck with SPI plots. The current SPI plot from SPEI package does not allow nice plots and I am not able to add the years along the x-axis. Kindly if anyone can help me to solve it.

(2) I have reworked the SPI data and created a data frame for different stations. However, when I use ggplot to make a similar plot as in (1), the chart is totally different. It appears that ggplot is not plotting the data continuously.

```
> head(s1)
  year month  rrP   rrV  rrPp   rrL   rrR   rrM   rrF  rrBC   rrA rrStM
1 1971     1 0.34  0.81  0.97  0.36  1.06  0.87  0.87  0.53  0.77  0.15
2 1971     2 0.80  1.96  1.07  0.64  1.59  1.29  0.85  0.66  1.76  0.96
```

3 1971     3 0.42 -0.43 -0.34 -0.46 -0.38 -0.01  0.04 -0.02 -0.46 -0.18
4 1971     4 0.65  0.93  1.69  1.83  0.82  1.54  1.02  0.94  0.64  0.68
5 1971     5 0.48  0.66  1.24  1.04  0.83  1.17  0.88  1.08 -0.45 -0.23
6 1971     6 0.19 -0.90 -0.75 -0.46 -1.25 -1.24 -0.46 -0.10 -0.50 -0.18
'''

Plot I obtained using the code below
[image]

```
s1<-data.frame (s1)
s1 = as.data.table(s1)
ggplot(data = s1, aes(x = year, y = rrP)) +
geom_col(data = s1[Mau <= 0], fill = "red") +
geom_col(data = s1[Mau >= 0], fill = "blue") +
theme_bw()
```

I am looking to plot figures like this

[image]

Thanking you in advance for your replies.
Vimal

Answer (score 0):

To have years in x-axis, you have to convert the data into `ts()` object like the following code

```
library(SPEI)
data(wichita) 
#calculate 6-month SPI
plot(spi(ts(wichita$PRCP,freq=12,start=c(1980,1)),scale = 6))
```

[image]

Or you can follow this question
[How to format the x-axis of the hard coded plotting function of SPEI package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960836/how-to-format-the-x-axis-of-the-hard-coded-plotting-function-of-spei-package-in/57714577#57714577)